# How to visually wrap lines at tab width in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea, word-wrap

In other editors (Visual Studio Code and Netbeans which I mostly use), I can enable word wrap. Lines will then be split (visually) over multiple lines if the line is longer that the view area.

How can the same be enabled in IntelliJ (Community)? Right now I can't get any kind of word wrap (coding Kotlin).

[image: Visual Studio Code word wrap]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The feature is called **Soft-wrap**. You can configure it here:
[image]